# Communication between WPF instances

Tags: .net, wpf, process

I have developed a WPF program that allow customers to select and purchase products, accept Credit Card (via gateway) and Gift card (IC Card).

The credit card part works like a champ and the program has been launched and installed to different stores.

---

**The Problem**

However, the .net library of IC Card Reader may having some issues causing exception that cannot be caught, even using the UnhandleException handler, around every 20 transactions, the program will just crash and exit. (Init reader machine > Init transaction > Get result > Log > release machine > Crash)

Since we do not own the reader library and we do not want to change the provider, so I would like to redesign the flow & logic to fix the above problem.

---

**The Current Flow**

The current flow of the program is simple, it starts from a 'standby' WPF Window to  show some posters, when user click on the screen, it will open a WPF Window that display products, finally another new WPF Window to ask the user to select payment method and pay the order.

---

**Ask for help**

When the program crashed, the entire program will be turned off and the Windows desktop will be shown. Even worse is the credits are deducted from the card but no products can be purchased. So my thought is to isolate different WPF Window into different process.

- Please let me know if this is a good practice to solve the problem?
- How could different WPF process communicate? (ex. If the 'child' Window changed the localization, how could it reflects to the 'parent' Window?)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: My totally wild guess would be that the problem has something to do with memory or threading. If Application.DispatcherUnhandledException event is not triggering, then I would suggest writing to logs for every mid-to-major point of your application. Find out which is the last log that the program writes before it crashes, and slowly adjust your logging points, as you slowly zoom in to the problematic section.

Comment: I have done the testing a few days before, the system will log at both server side & client side, so I can roughly confirm the problem maker is the 'Machine Release' function which I can do nothing (try-catch block added) but since there is no exact exception log present, so it cannot be really confirmed.

Comment: Is that "Machine Release" part running on multiple threads? Generally, if Application.DispatcherUnhandledException fails to catch an exception, it means that the exception occurred on a non-main-UI thread. If you place your try-catch outside of the entry point of the new thread, it will not catch it either.

Comment: Does the [event viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)  reveal something?

Comment: Yes, the reader's library contains quite a lot problem, so most of the library calls go into a new thread, the try-catch block is located in the mentioned thread but I don't know how is the library inside.

Comment: Do you have any async calls? If your exception is thrown inside an async block that is not correctly awaited, the exception might be swallowed by the task.

Comment: Most of the time, doing things on another thread without proper planning is simply inviting more trouble for yourself. While it is nice when things work out without errors, but when errors come, they will silently kill your application. Also, this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) is quite a good read. Lastly, try contacting the guys that made the reader libraries, see if you can work out some solution with them.

Comment: No async calls invoked and I have done something like task.continueWith(Log Sth, When Exception)..

Comment: Yup, the hurry of this project causes a lot of not planned threads and that's why I would like to re-develop the program..